# Style and Script is not loading while working with Pechkin on Https protocal

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, pechkin

I am using `pechkin` library in `C#` a wrapper for `wkhtmltopdf`. It's working fine with `http:` protocal but when using `https:`, scripts and style are not loading in pdf.
Thanks in advance.

> View:
>
> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
>     <meta charset="utf-8" />
>     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@Url.AbsoluteUrl("Content/Favicon/favicon.ico")" />
>
>     @Styles.Render(Url.AbsoluteUrl("Content/themes/base/css"))
>     @Styles.Render(Url.AbsoluteUrl("Content/themes/css"))
>     @Scripts.Render(Url.AbsoluteUrl("Scripts/library"))
>     @Scripts.Render(Url.AbsoluteUrl("Scripts/Common"))
>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <div class="pad-none printBody size-100">
>         <div class="tabs-nav">
>             <div class="global-pad">
>                 <div class="row">
>                     <div id="divReportGrids" class="size-100">
>                         @string.Concat(AppConstants.Delimiters.StartDelimiter,
>                                AppConstants.Common.PrintBodyPlaceholder,
>                                AppConstants.Delimiters.EndDelimiter)
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>
>     </div>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Code:
>
> ```
>          var documentConfig = new ObjectConfig().SetZoomFactor(1)
>                                                 .SetScreenMediaType(true)
>                                                .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
>                                                 .SetAllowLocalContent(true)
>                                                 .SetLoadImages(true)
>                                                 .SetRunJavascript(true)
>                                                 .SetPrintBackground(true)
>                                                 .SetRenderDelay(10000);
>         documentConfig.Footer.SetFont(new Font("Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif", 4F, FontStyle.Regular));
>         documentConfig.Footer.SetRightText(@"[page] of [topage]");
>         documentConfig.Footer.SetContentSpacing(5.00);
>
>         var globalConfig = new GlobalConfig()
>                     .SetDocumentTitle("POB Report")
>                     .SetPaperSize(PaperKind.A4)
>                     .SetOutputDpi(360);
>
>         var pechkin = new SynchronizedPechkin(globalConfig);
>         //Convert html to pdf
>         byte[] htmlBytes = pechkin.Convert(documentConfig, completeHtml);
> ```

Comment: Are these resources (scripts/css) available over https?

Comment: @ArunSelin Yes, they are available with there absolute url.